# How to set journal-mode of Sqlite3 in ruby-on-rails

Tags: sqlite, ruby-on-rails-5

I try to set journal-mode of Sqlite3 in my Ruby-on-Rails project.

It seems that ruby-on-rails uses default journal-mode of sqlite, i.e. 'delete', as i saw a journal file in folder 'db' when I updated database and it was deleted when update was done. I hope to set jouranl-mode to be "WAL" or "memory". 
I tried Sqlite command line

```
PRAGMA main.journal_mode=WAL
```

but it does not affect application in ruby-on-rails.

Finally I made it by changing source code of sqlite3_adapter.rb

I changed a function in file : activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb

```
def configure_connection  
    # here are original codes
    execute("PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL", "SCHEMA")  
end
```

Because configure_connection is called by initialize of SQLite3Adapter

It does not sound nice solution although it works.
Is there any nicer way to set journal-mode of Sqlite3 in Ruby-on-Rails(version is 5.1.4)? For example configuration options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been a while since I've had to do this, but you should be able to use an initializer so you don't need to patch the source.

Putting something like this in `config/initializers/configure_sqlite_journal.rb`

```
if c = ::ActiveRecord::Base.connection
    c.execute 'PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL'
end
```

Should do what you want

Comment: It works well and gracefully. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

I found a better answer in here: [Speed up your Rails sqlite database for large dataset](https://gist.github.com/datenimperator/7602535), more performance and configure:

The code( I put this into config/initializers/speedup_sqlite3.rb ):

```
if ::ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config[:adapter] == 'sqlite3'
    if c = ::ActiveRecord::Base.connection
    # see http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html for details

    # Page size of the database. The page size must be a power of two between 512 and 65536 inclusive
    c.execute 'PRAGMA main.page_size=4096;'

    # Suggested maximum number of database disk pages that SQLite will hold in memory at once per open database file
    c.execute 'PRAGMA main.cache_size=10000;'

    # Database connection locking-mode. The locking-mode is either NORMAL or EXCLUSIVE
    c.execute 'PRAGMA main.locking_mode=EXCLUSIVE;'

    # Setting of the "synchronous" flag, "NORMAL" means sync less often but still more than none
    c.execute 'PRAGMA main.synchronous=NORMAL;'

    # Journal mode for database, WAL=write-ahead log
    c.execute 'PRAGMA main.journal_mode=WAL;'

    # Storage location for temporary tables, indices, views, triggers
    c.execute 'PRAGMA main.temp_store = MEMORY;'
  end
end
```